# Why is my python file not able to be imported into my pycharm program

Tags: python, python-import

I have a code in a python file named happy_histogram.py :

```
 __author__ = 'Bauer'

from graphics import GraphicsWindow

def drawHappyFace(canvas,x,y):
canvas.setColor("yellow")
canvas.setOutline("black")
#canvas.drawOval(100, 100, 30, 30)
canvas.drawOval(x, y, 30, 30)
canvas.setColor("black")
#canvas.drawOval(108, 110, 5, 5)
canvas.drawOval(x+8, y+10, 5, 5)
#canvas.drawOval(118, 110, 5, 5)
canvas.drawOval(x+18, y+10, 5, 5)
#canvas.drawLine(110, 122, 113, 125)
canvas.drawLine(x+10, y+22, x+13, y+25)
#canvas.drawLine(113, 125, 117, 125)
canvas.drawLine(x+13, y+25, x+17, y+25)
#canvas.drawLine(117, 125, 120, 122)
canvas.drawLine(x+17, y+25, x+20, y+22)
```

I need to import this into my pycharm program to use the functions.
I tried a few ways to import, but they dont work.
NOTE: The pycharm project and the python file are in the same folder.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by import, but the indentation was wrong. And I guess the package-name where you were trying to import GraphicsWindow from.

First download:

> http://www.ezgraphics.org/uploads/Software/Download/ezgraphics-2.1.tar.gz

Install it:

> pip install ezgraphics-2.1.tar.gz

Then try this:

```
__author__ = 'Bauer'

from ezgraphics import GraphicsWindow


def drawHappyFace(canvas,x,y):
    canvas.setColor("yellow")
    canvas.setOutline("black")
    #canvas.drawOval(100, 100, 30, 30)
    canvas.drawOval(x, y, 30, 30)
    canvas.setColor("black")
    #canvas.drawOval(108, 110, 5, 5)
    canvas.drawOval(x+8, y+10, 5, 5)
    #canvas.drawOval(118, 110, 5, 5)
    canvas.drawOval(x+18, y+10, 5, 5)
    #canvas.drawLine(110, 122, 113, 125)
    canvas.drawLine(x+10, y+22, x+13, y+25)
    #canvas.drawLine(113, 125, 117, 125)
    canvas.drawLine(x+13, y+25, x+17, y+25)
    #canvas.drawLine(117, 125, 120, 122)
    canvas.drawLine(x+17, y+25, x+20, y+22)

    drawHappyFace(GraphicsWindow().canvas(),400,400)
```

I guess you want something like this:

```
__author__ = 'Bauer'

from ezgraphics import GraphicsWindow
import time

def drawHappyFace(canvas,x,y):
    canvas.setHeight(200)
    canvas.setWidth(200)
    canvas.setColor("yellow")
    canvas.setOutline("black")
    canvas.drawOval(100, 100, 30, 30)
    canvas.drawOval(x, y, 30, 30)
    canvas.setColor("black")
    canvas.drawOval(108, 110, 5, 5)
    canvas.drawOval(x+8, y+10, 5, 5)
    canvas.drawOval(118, 110, 5, 5)
    canvas.drawOval(x+18, y+10, 5, 5)
    canvas.drawLine(110, 122, 113, 125)
    canvas.drawLine(x+10, y+22, x+13, y+25)
    canvas.drawLine(113, 125, 117, 125)
    canvas.drawLine(x+13, y+25, x+17, y+25)
    canvas.drawLine(117, 125, 120, 122)
    canvas.drawLine(x+17, y+25, x+20, y+22)
    time.sleep(10000)

    drawHappyFace(GraphicsWindow().canvas(),10,10)
```